# How to call hash map in Karate test when calling a Java function?

Tags: java, karate

I want to call a Java class inside my Karate test which takes 3 inputs, one is file_path, and 2 is hash map.

```
public class testing {
    public static void testing(String filePath, HashMap<String, String> refMap, HashMap<String, String> modifyMap) {
        TestPdfProcessorKt.utilPDFProcess(filePath, refMap, modifyMap);
    }
```

```
Feature: Calling Kotlin function in Karate

  Scenario: Call Kotlin function
    * def first = {"name":"Mike"}
    * def second = {"name":"Jack"}
    * def result = Java.type('testing').testing("/Users/file", first, second)
```

I googled it and I couldn't find an answer

Comment: as far as I know it should work. try creating a simple example using the quickstart and take it from there. `testing` should be on the java classpath. take the help of a friend who knows java if needed: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Get-Started:-Maven-and-Gradle